# sorting a react-native listview

Tags: listview, react-native, listitem

I'm trying to sort a list in my react-native `View`
 - the onClick triggering the sortArrayAsc function is working
 - the sortArrayAsc resultset is working
 - uncommenting the debugger part shows the values in the dataSource are in the newly sorted order
 The issue I have is that I thought using setState would automatically re-render the list ... which isn't happening.

If not, any ideas what I'm missing or what's to do?
 Any guidance / code updates would be most appreciated
 Cheers

```
export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 } );
    sortedData = data;
    this.state = { dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows(sortedData) };
  }

  sortArrayAsc(array, key) {
    return array.sort(function (a,b) {
      console.info(b.amount)
      return b.amount < a.amount ? -1
           : b.amount > a.amount ? 1
           : 0
    })
  }

  _onPress() {
    sortedData = this.sortArrayAsc(sortedData, 'amount')
    let dataSource = this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(sortedData)
    //debugger
    this.setState = ( this.state.dataSource: dataSource )
  }

  _renderRow (rowData, sectionID) {
    return (
      <ListItem
        ... 
        onPress = { () => { this._onPress() } }
        ...
      />
    )
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <List>
          <ListView
            dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow = {this._renderRow.bind(this)}
          />
        </List>
      </View>
    )
  }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let  ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 } );
export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    sortedData = data;   // this line seems redundent you can remove this
    this.state = { dataSource:ds.cloneWithRows(data) };//I used ds, just for the shake of name
  }

  sortArrayAsc(array, key) {
    return array.sort(function (a,b) {
      console.info(b.amount)
      return b.amount < a.amount ? -1
           : b.amount > a.amount ? 1
           : 0
    })
  }

  _onPress() {
    sortedData = this.sortArrayAsc(sortedData, 'amount')
    //no need of these lines
    /*let dataSource = //      this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(sortedData)*/
    
    //debugger
    //this.setState = ( this.state.dataSource: dataSource )
    /*you should look in the react doc for setState(https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html), you may be trying to use 
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
  return {myInteger: prevState.myInteger + props.step};
});*/
    this.setState({
      dataSource:ds.cloneWithRows(sortedData)
    });
  }

  _renderRow (rowData, sectionID) {
    return (
      <ListItem
        ... 
        onPress = { () => { this._onPress() } }
        ...
      />
    )
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <List>
          <ListView
            dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow = {this._renderRow.bind(this)}
          />
        </List>
      </View>
    )
  }

};
```

Comment: Hi
Thank you very much for including comments throughout and the `setState` link.

I used your solution to debug my original and it boiled down to the `this.state` in the `let dataSource = this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(sortedData)`  line

I included `this.state` originally because I was getting `Cannot read cloneWithRows` errors which this resolved.  Unfortunately it was just masking the problem !!

Therefore this single line change `dataSource = dataSource.cloneWithRows(sortedData)`  is working.

I'll also incorporate your additional points :-)
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

For setState, can you try this:

> this.setState({   dataSource: dataSource });

Comment: Hi  Thanks for the update.  Unfortunately it's not updating the view list  :-(

Comment: Hi, further to the update from Manjeet, this point was also required :-)
Namely the use of the curly-braces in my original setState code.
Thank you for reviewing/commenting on this, Kush R.

Answer (score 0):

Try to log a console in render as

```
console.log(this.state.dataSource);
```

See if it prints the correct value while rendering. To make sure dataSource is set new value only after `this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(sortedData)`, write the setState in a callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try passing an `array` to dataSource.cloneWithRows(array) instead of `object`?

I am not sure if your `sortedData` is `array` or `object`.

Because, I had a problem with `ListView`, too. The rendered items is not sorted in the same way as the data I provided.

Here was my data:

```
let data = {
    key1: object,
    key2: object,
    key3: object,
    key4: object,
    key5: object,
    key6: object
}
```

This is what I have found when I logged the result using:

```
console.log(Object.keys(data))
```

The result is:

```
["key3", "key1", "key5", "key4", "key2"]
```

Which are the same order as the the rendered items in ListView. So, I change my code from:

```
const dataSource = new ListView.DataSource(
    rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => (r1 !== r2)
})
this.setState({
    ds: dataSource.cloneWithRows(data)
})
```

to:

```
let dataArray = []

// Sort the keys out
let keys = Object.keys(data).sort()

// Push them into dataArray
keys.forEach(key => dataArray.push(data[key]))

const dataSource = new ListView.DataSource(
    rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => (r1 !== r2)
})

// Now I am passing array datatype instead of object datatype.
this.setState({
    dataSource.cloneWithRows(dataArray)
})
```

My problem solved.